# Initialize pointer of strings without new keyword in c++

Tags: c++

I am using c++.
I want to initialize pointer of string. I have been doing it using :

```
string *strPtr = new string("abcd");
```

But I don't want to use heap memory. Use somthing like this :

```
string *strPtr;
// initialize with "abcd"
```

How can I do it using stack memory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can declare a string on the stack and then take the address of it:

```
std::string str{"abcd"};
std::string* ptr_str = &str;
```

But I'm sure it would be more convenient for you to handle a reference, a smart pointer, or maybe a `std::string_view`. Raw pointers should be used in some very specific cases nowadays.

Comment: The most convenient would probably be just using `str` directly.

Comment: I recommend adding a quick code example of using a reference (yeah, the asker should already know this, but the question suggests they don't or don't quite get it) and possibly the `string_view`.

Comment: Nice, correct, just do not use the pointer. Should be almost like unnecessary... The last part was for the author of the question :).

Comment: Thanks for the answers everyone. I thought I tired the above solution and did get the error but it wasnt the case. My bad. Unfortunately I have to use it as a point for somw reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```cpp
string str("abcd");
string *strPtr = &str;
```

Sometimes you can get away with using `alloca()` to allocate memory on the stack, you'd need to allocate twice, once for metadata and once for data and then `reinterpret_cast`...

Comment: `alloca()` would be horrible for a `std::string`. But, if you must, it would be easier to simply `allloca()` a block that is `>= sizeof(string)` in size w/ proper alignment added, and then use `placement-new` to construct a new `string` inside that memory.  Just be sure to call `~string()` on the memory before it goes out of scope.